# Using google translate api POST method, returns 404

Tags: c#, google-translate

So basically I have some french text and want to traduce it in english using c#.

I'm using google translate api, which was working fine until i had a text.length > 1000 ....  then I realized that I must use POST method.

Since I use the post method, it returns me 404.

btw i know the api is deprecated, I though it would be cool anyways but I'm starting to realize maybe i should use bing ?

```
 string fromLanguage = "fr";
 string toLanguage = "en";
 String apiKey = "AIzasdfasdfJvWKNioZwLg-3kyYsm4_dao";
 String apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";
 string tmpTranslatedContent = Translate(apiUrl, "salut la planete", apiKey, fromLanguage, toLanguage);


public string Translate(string url, string text, string key, string fromLanguage, string toLanguage)
        {
            PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter();
            post.Url = url;
            post.PostItems.Add("key", key);
            post.PostItems.Add("source", fromLanguage);
            post.PostItems.Add("target", toLanguage);
            post.PostItems.Add("q", text);
            post.Type = PostSubmitter.PostTypeEnum.Post;
            string result = post.Post();
            return result;
       }
```

[PostSubmitter is a class](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx) i found when searching google

Comments on the site are saying it works.....

the main part of the class looks like this

```
HttpWebRequest request=null;
if (m_type==PostTypeEnum.Post)
{
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
using(Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: whats the deal with removing the yo from the top of my message is there some sort of fake-serious talk only going on over here

Comment: works fine, ive also tryed doing it myself at first, had same 404 problem. Looks like its a probleme with https and post method...

Comment: "salut la planete": "greeting the planet"? Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Comment: what is your actual question?  whether you should use bing or is there a programming question here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old, but I just ran into a similar problem but with PHP instead of C# and the fix should be quite similar.

Basically, even though you are using POST, you still need to tell Google that from a REST point of view you are actually doing a GET.  This can be done with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header, setting it to be: X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET

Google tells me that as ASP.NET MVC, version 2, there is a method HttpHelper.HttpMethodOverride that will allow you to do this.

According to the Google Translate API however, text is still limited to 5k even when posting.

Comment: I ended up using get and a loop, spliting the text in small pieces of 1k. Yeah i know... but it works for me and it seems stable.